# visual studio stops working after .net framework update

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

i'm new on visual studio. i have visual studio 2010 installed with .Net framework v4.0.30128 . everything was working fine until the .Net framework updated to v4.0.30319 .  visual studio is not starting. when i try running it, a dailog apears saying 'the operation could not be completed'.

- i had to uninstall the both .Net framework versions v.4.0.30128 and v4.0.30319 and visual studio.
- then i reinstalled .Net framework v4.0.030128 and visual studio 2010. it started working again
- the issue is, next day same problem is there. .Net framework is automatically updated to v4.0.30319 and visual studio in not starting. same 'the operation could not be completed'

Any ideas please. why can visual studio not work with updated .Net framework. is there a workaround ?? please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed [VS2010 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) ok?

Comment: @Roger, i tried doing it but it says: "A compatible version of Visual Studio 2010 was not detected on the system. This update is designed for only the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010"  shall i reinstall it !!!

Comment: You cannot keep the RC version of VS running.  Beta and release candidates are time-limited and not guaranteed to be compatible with the RTM version.  If you don't want to pay the license fee then use the free Express edition.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'll go for the express edition